# ¿Cómo coloco texto en un textView de un layout desde Main Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]¿Cómo puedo cambiar el texto de un textView de un cuadro de diálogo que está en otra layout desde el MainActivity? El problema es que se cierra la app al intentar establecer el texto en el cuadro de diálogo.

La layout está en otro archivo XML.

Este es mi código:

```
public void CuadrazoOver() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.timeover, null);

    builder.setView(view);

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    TextView puntuacion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.puntaje);

    puntuacion.setText("50");
}
```

Comment: Que se muestra en el LogCat?, agrega el layout timeover.xml

Comment: ya agregue una imagen, pasa que no puedo colocarle un texto al textView que se ve ahi al de la imagen

Comment: El archivo timeover.xml ? Trata también de revisar el LogCat, puedes solucionar un problema en unos segundos en lugar de varias horas.

Comment: 2022-06-29 18:01:18.541 5034-5034/com.example.ahorcado E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ahorcado, PID: 5034
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.ahorcado.MainActivity.CuadrazoOver(MainActivity.java:1275)

Comment: intenta el findViewById de puntaje con la vista inflada de timeover: view.findViewById(R.id.puntaje)

Answer (score 1):

Si el TextView esta en otro XML tienes que llamar al id de ese TextView en ese XML. En el layout "timeover" el TextView tiene que tener como id "puntaje"
y en el

```
TextView puntuacion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.puntaje);
```

tienes que inflar el view de ese xml

```
TextView puntuacion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.puntaje);
```

ejemplo:

timeover.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/puntaje"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Main.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn1;
    EditText et1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        et1 = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        btn1.setOnClickListener(view -> CuadrazoOver() );
    }

    public void CuadrazoOver() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.timeover, null);

        builder.setView(view);

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        TextView puntuacion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.puntaje);

        String text = ""+et1.getText().toString();

        puntuacion.setText(text);
    }
}
```